# Varying number of for-loops

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to write a code that could print something like this

```
-xv
-xvv
-xvvv
-xvvvv
-xvvvvv

-xxv
-xxvv
-xxvvv
-xxvvvv
-xxvvvvv

-xxxv
-xxxvv
-xxxvvv
-xxxvvvv
-xxxvvvvv
```

The extra spacing between the 3 "groups" are just for clarity's sake. The maximum number of '-' is 1, 'x' is 3, 'v' is 5, and the number of each symbol increments.

To draw this diagram, I have the following code

```
for (k = 1 ; k <= num_dash ; k++)
{
   for (i = 1 ; i <= num_x ; i++)
   {
      for (j = 1 ; j <= num_v ; j+++)
      {
         for (k1 = 0 ; k1 < k ; k++)
            printf("-");
         for (i1 = 0 ; i1 < i ; i++)
            printf("x");
         for (j1 = 0 ; j1 < j ; j++)
            printf("v");
         printf("\n");
      }
   }
}
```

This is when I know there are 3 different kinds of symbols. Is it possible to do the same if the number of symbols are only known at runtime? For example, what if I want the same program to also be able to print

```
xv
xvv
xvvv
xvvvv
xvvvvv

xxv
xxvv
xxvvv
xxvvvv
xxvvvvv

xxxv
xxxvv
xxxvvv
xxxvvvv
xxxvvvvv
```

In this case, my code would only be

```
   for (i = 1 ; i <= num_x ; i++)
   {
      for (j = 1 ; j <= num_v ; j+++)
      {
         for (i1 = 0 ; i1 < i ; i++)
            printf("x");
         for (j1 = 0 ; j1 < j ; j++)
            printf("v");
         printf("\n");
      }
   }
```

And there are only 2 for-loops instead of 3. Can I write my code such that the number of for-loops varies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_aux(char **symbols, int *times, int len, int pos, char *acc){
    int i;
    char *p;

    if(pos == len){
        printf("%s\n", acc);
        return;
    }
    p = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(symbols[pos])*times[pos]+strlen(acc)+1);
    for(i=0;i<times[pos];++i){
        int j;
        *p='\0';
        strcpy(p, acc);
        for(j=0;j<=i;++j){
            strcat(p, symbols[pos]);
        }
        print_aux(symbols, times, len, pos + 1, p);
    }
    if(pos + 1 == len)// when last symbol
        printf("\n",pos);
    free(p);
}

//wrap function
void print(char **symbols, int *times, int len){
    print_aux(symbols, times, len, 0, "");
}

int main() {
    int i,n;
    char **symbols;
    int  *times;

    fprintf(stderr,"number of symbols :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    symbols=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);
    times = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        char wk[128];
        fprintf(stderr,"input symbol [%d]:", i+1);
        scanf(" %s", wk);
        symbols[i] = strdup(wk);
        fprintf(stderr,"maximum number of \"%s\":",wk);
        scanf(" %d", &times[i]);
    }

    print(symbols, times, n);

    {   //release the allocated area
        for(i=0;i<n;++i){
            free(symbols[i]);
        }
        free(symbols);
        free(times);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use functions instead of innermost for loops and pass the characters and number of iterations as parameters to that function.